# Как изменить ввод username "email" на "phone" для API аутентификации (Passport)?

Tags: laravel, api, auth, аутентификация, passport

Ребят, как можно изменить ввод username "email" на "phone" для API аутентификации (Passport)?

Чтобы получить токен

Для обычной авторизации я в LoginController переопределил метод

```
function sername(){
    return "phone";
}
```

И всё работает замечательно

Получается у меня сейчас на самом сайте для авторизация в качестве логина используется Phone

а через API (что-бы получить TOKEN) нужно вводить email

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить метод findForPassport в модель User

```
public function findForPassport($identifier) {
    return $this->where('phone', $identifier)->first();
}
```

И добавить 'phone' в $fillable

```
protected $fillable = [
    'phone', 'password',
];
```

Проверено в Laravel 5.8